# Explicitly specialized members need their containing class templates to be explicitly specialized as well

Tags: c++, templates, member, explicit-specialization

I read in many articles, that for class template when specializing
member template, the class that containing specialized member template also shall be explicitly specialized. Is there a point about it in standard and is there any reason to have such restriction? 
I mean under the hood.

Why this is not allowed.

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
   template <typename U>
   void foo()
   {}
};

template <typename T>
 template <>
void A<T>::foo<int>()
{}
```

Comment: See [CWG 727](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#727) and [N4090](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4090.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

[temp.expl.spec]/16:

> In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class
>   template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, **the
>   member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain
>   unspecialized, except that the declaration shall not explicitly
>   specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates
>   are not explicitly specialized as well.**  [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template <class T1> class A {
>     template<class T2> class B {
>         template<class T3> void mf1(T3);
>         void mf2();
>     };
> };
>
> template <> template <class X>
> class A<int>::B {
>     template <class T> void mf1(T);
> };
>
> template <> template <> template<class T>
> void A<int>::B<double>::mf1(T t) { }
> template <class Y> template <>
> void A<Y>::B<double>::mf2() { } // ill-formed; B<double> is specialized 
>                                 // but its enclosing class template A is not
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]